# Twitter Bootstrap Row Filter / Search Box

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, search, filter

I'm having trouble finding a tutorial on how to create a simple search query, or row filter, for Twitter Bootstrap. I've tried many, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or the plugins are not compatible with Bootstrap. Please help if you can.

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Declare the custom selector 'containsIgnoreCase'.
      $.expr[':'].containsIgnoreCase = function(n,i,m){
          return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
      };

      $("#search").keyup(function(){

          $("#tabela").find("tr").hide();
          var data = this.value.split(" ");
          var jo = $("#tabela").find("tr");
          $.each(data, function(i, v){

               //Use the new containsIgnoreCase function instead
               jo = jo.filter("*:containsIgnoreCase('"+v+"')");
          });

          jo.show();

      }).focus(function(){
          this.value="";
          $(this).css({"color":"black"});
          $(this).unbind('focus');
      }).css({"color":"#C0C0C0"});
});
```

Nothing with this... Maybe I'm missing any "id" on my table or search box, I'm  new with this.

Answer (score 46):

Here's what I use:

```
$('input.filter').live('keyup', function() {
    var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
    $('.searchable tr').hide();
        $('.searchable tr').filter(function() {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
    });
```

To use it, you just create a table, with a tbody with the class "searchable" and then an input with class "filter" somewhere on your page (I prefer to put them in a Bootstrap Popup behind a search icon).

Comment: Sir. I don't know if you're still around, but the code above saved me hours of frustration. Thank You!!

Comment: Nice snippet. Very useful!

Comment: With jQuery > 1.7 `.live()` should be `.on()`.

Comment: I need to show Add New in the list if i don't have the item can u help me with that ??

Comment: OMG! You have no idea how much this saved me, I have been searching for a solution like this for days and no one could help me. Thank you Thank you Thank you

Answer (score 21):

This is live example of solution provided by Filipp Lepalaan. Many thanks for this small and perfect code.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/giorgitbs/52aK9/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

(function ($) {

    $('#filter').keyup(function () {

        var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.searchable tr').hide();
        $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();

    })

}(jQuery));
```

});

Comment: I need to show Add New in the list if i don't have the item can u help me with that ??