# Filtering bootstrap JS Table row column based on wildcard

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have created a table with bootstrap using the `boostrapTable` function. I am in need of trying to filter a table by a column, but I need to have a wildcard in place to just look for a specific string of `Yes` or `No`.

From what I have read `fnFilter` for dataTables would do what I need, but I cant find the equivalent for `bootstrapTable`

It seems like this would be what would work for datatables, but does not work for bootstrap

```
$('.spammy_links').click(function() {
    $table.fnFilter("^"+"search_string"+"$", column_name, true);
});
```

Here is what a bootstrap version of filtering looks like, but has no wild card options. This actually works but only of the record contains ONLY `Yes` or `No`

```
$('.spammy_links').click(function() {
    $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', {
        indexed: 'Yes'
    });
});
```

Is there anything similar in bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution thanks to [Twitter Bootstrap Row Filter / Search Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713622/twitter-bootstrap-row-filter-search-box)

I altered the title a bit to be more descriptive.

All I needed to do what add this code which I altered a bit

```
$('tbody').addClass('searchable'); //<-- Add class to tbody for filter below
$('.spammy_links').on('click', function() {
    var rex = new RegExp('No', 'i');
    $('.searchable tr').hide();
    $('.searchable tr').filter(':has(td:nth-child(2):contains("No"))',function() {
        return rex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
});
```